# Will this void function return a value at all? Or do I have to add a "&"?

Tags: c++

Suppose I have a previously written class called Box. I have the following constructor and void function:

```
Box::Box (double height, double width, double length)
{
    setHeight(height);
    setWidth(width);
    setLength(length);
} 

void Box::setHeight(double h)
{
    height = h;
}
```

In my main () function, I later declare:

```
Box box1(2.4, 7.1, 5.0);
```

Will 2.4 become the height of my box?

How?

The voidBox::setHeight(double h) doesn't have a "return" value because it's a void function? So how will it set height?

Comment: `void` functions don't return values at all.

Comment: Returning a value has nothing to do with setting a member.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I don't think that what the OP meant, he probably meant should he change `void` for it to return if necessary

Comment: Functions can have effects other than through their return values. *"So how will it set height?"* Presumably through `height = h;`.

Comment: *Will 2.4 become the height of my box?* - You could check this part in less time and effort than asking about it.

Comment: Look up *initialization list* in your favorite C++ reference.  You can initialize values in the constructor without having to call setter functions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Will 2.4 become the height of my box? How?

Yes, 2.4 will become the height stored in the member variable of your `Box` object.

`Box::setHeight` is a *member function*. It gets an implicit reference to the object on which it is called. When invoked from the constructor, member function gets the a reference to the object being constructed. That is why the assignment

```
height = h;
```

inside `Box::setHeight` would modify the `height` member variable of your `Box` object.

> do I have to add a `&`?

No. A reference to the object being constructed is passed implicitly; no action is required on your part.

**Note 1:** In order for your code to compile, `Box` needs to have a member variable called `height`. This is different from the `height` in the constructor, which is a parameter passed to the constructor from the caller.

**Note 2:** You can assign member variable `height` in the constructor by referencing it with `this` keyword:

```
this->height = height;
```

You could also use initialization list to initialize `height`:

```
Box::Box (double height, double width, double length)
  : height(height)
  , width(width)
  , length(length) 
{
   // The body can be left empty
}
```

Comment: I think this is the right answer, but for the sake of clearing up all confusion, you may include something about how the `height` in the constructor is quite different from `height` in `setHeight()`.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `Box` looks something like this:

```
class Box {
private:
    double height, width, length;
public:
    Box(double height, double width, double length);
    void setHeight(double h);
    void setWidth(double w);
    void setLength(double l);
};
```

Then `Box::setHeight` is setting the `height` member of the class.  Member functions can access data members of the class as well as any parameters passed in, so the function doesn't need to return anything to assign a value to the member.